# Passing data with NavigationSplitView to the second column

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a macOS app with two columns. The left column is a list that presents the filename and date of the unit (file) that I'm working on. The second column, to the right, should present the content of each file when selected.

I have an array that contains that information and I create a list for the left column that presents each item. I added a `detail:` with a `TextEditor` that allows the user to see the data and modify it if necessary. I have been trying to set the  `@State var text` to the contents of `currentunit.text` but I don't know how to pass that the `detail:`. If I try to assign it (as in `text = x`) then I get an error saying that it doesn't conform to View.

I tried then to maybe load it by getting the index of the current selected unit, using the selectedUnitId, and using something like this to get the index:

```
func getIndex(uuid: UUID) -> Int? {
        return data.units.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == uuid})
}
```

But I get nowhere with a collection of different errors.

Regardless, how do I pass data to the `detail:` part of the code? I have looked into many examples of NavigationSplitView and they are all very similar, just showing the basic usage and that's it.

Thanks!

Code:

```
struct Unit: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var text: String
    var date = Date()
    var dateText: String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d yyyy, h:mm a"
        return df.string(from: date)
    }
    var changed: Bool = false
}


final class UnitModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("unit") public var units: [Unit] = []
    init() {
        self.units = self.units.sorted(by: {
            $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending
        })
    }
    
    func sortList() {
        self.units = self.units.sorted(by: {
            $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: UnitModel
    @State var selectedUnitId: UUID?
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
              List(data.units, selection: $selectedUnitId) { currentunit in
                  VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                      Text(currentunit.filename)
                      Text(currentunit.dateText)
                  }
              }
          } detail: {
             // here: how do I preload $text with the text from the unit?
              VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                  TextEditor(text: $text)
              }
          }
    }
    
}
```

I also tried:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: UnitModel
    @State var selectedNoteId: UUID?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
              List(data.units, selection: $selectedNoteId) { currentunit in
                  NavigationLink{
                      UnitView(unit: currentunit, text: currentunit.text)
                  } label: {
                      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                          Text(currentunit.filename)
                          Text(currentunit.dateText)
                      }
                  }
              }
          } detail: {
              Text("Select a unit.")

          }
    }
}

struct UnitView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: UnitModel
    var unit: Unit
    @State var text: String
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

But again, I don't know how to initialize the `text` variable with the text of the current unit. I only get the initial one selected, and even tho I can see a new unit selected, the text remains the same and doesn't update.

**UPDATED** if I change the code to use `NavigationView` then it works as it should, so what's going with the new way that Apple is make us use now? Namely `NavigationSplitView` and `NavigationStack`?

Here's the code that work as it should but it's deprecated according to Apple:

```
    NavigationView {
          List(data.units, selection: $selectedNoteId) { currentunit in
              
              NavigationLink(
                    destination: UnitView(unit: currentunit, text: currentunit.text),
                    label: {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(currentunit.filename)
                            Text(currentunit.dateText)
                        }
                    }
              )
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [Defining the source of truth using a custom binding](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts/defining-the-source-of-truth-using-a-custom-binding)
tutorial covers this. Your code would look something like this:

```
} detail: {
    DetailView(unitID: selectedUnitID) // not sure why they used binding
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let unitID: Unit.ID
    @EnvironmentObject private var store: UnitModel

    private var unitBinding: Binding<Unit> {
        Binding {
            if let id = unitID {
                return store.unit(with: id) ?? Unit.emptyUnit()
            } else {
                return Unit.emptyUnit()
            }
        } set: { updatedUnit in
            store.update(updatedUnit)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

          if store.contains(unitID) {
              VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                  TextEditor(text: unitBinding.text)
              }
          }
          else {
              Text("Select Unit")
          } 
    }

}
```

Note there currently (as of Xcode 14.2) is a known bug with the text cursor when using a TextField in the detail pane. Check by entering text, move cursor to middle and try to enter a character. The bug is the cursor jumps to the end.

Comment: Thank you but I still can't update the text on TextEditor if something was stored on the unit.text already. I'm going to play with this further but why change from something that was working (`NavigationView` -> `NavigationLink`) to something that is rather complicated to use... ah... My mistake from moving away from Obj-c.

Comment: `Unit.emptyUnit()` doesn't exist. Same with `updatedUnit`. I don't know where that's coming from and I can quite figure out from Apple's article either...

Comment: you have to code that, copy emptyRecipe() in their project

Comment: I see... All that so I can use two columns when the past way of doing this was working ok... Thank you Apple.

Comment: The old way had a major problem that if you scrolled an activated link off screen it would deactivate. The new has its own problems though. I think this June they will try again. Personally I feel that navigation just doesn't fit into SwiftUI's state driven design.

Comment: I hear you... Meanwhile I can't get this to work and I can't update my app to be compliant with the way apple wants things done...